# IntelliJ reporting 'illegal hexadecimal escape sequence' on my string that is valid

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I'd like to dynamically generate a RegularExpression pattern in Java:

```
String s = "\uD83E\uDD81";
int codePoint = Character.toCodePoint(s.charAt(0), s.charAt(1));

String pattern = "\\x{" + String.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(codePoint)).toUpperCase() + "}";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(s);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

This code compiles and runs correctly. However, IntelliJ IDEA gives the following error `'illegal hexadecimal escape sequence` for the `"\\x{"`.

I'm using Java 8 and IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1

Is this a bug? The problem appears to be in the analysis that IntellJ does for the passed argument to the `Pattern.compile` method.

Comment: What value does the `codePoints` contain and how is the `pattern` used afterward?

Comment: @Nikolas I updated the code.

Comment: And Java version?

Comment: It's already in the description ;-) Java 8 and IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted compiles and runs without issue. If you create the pattern using the same literal string, IntelliJ does not complain:

```
String s = "\uD83E\uDD81";
String pattern = "\\x{1F981}";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(s);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

So yes, this looks like a bug in IntelliJ.